# Ubuntu Touch (Nexus 4, Developer & Stable Channel)

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

Did install without any problems.
Firstly installed the image from "Stable", as the problems occurred, installed from Developer Channel.
On both installation (factory reset has been performed as well) one major and one minor problem exist:

major: I can't connect to WiFi's with a 60 to 63 digit long passphrase (WPA/WPA2). I can connect to WiFi ("guest WiFi") of the same router(s), which have a far shorter passphrase.
Is there a way to overcome that problem? (Other than to change the passphrase. Yes, I am 100% sure, I entered the correct code.)

minor: I can copy text, but can't paste it! (e.g. to the WiFi-passphrase :-)) No "option" to paste appears. :-/
Any solution for that available?

Tanks in advance!